# Flutterfire firebase_auth does not work anymore

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an application using flutter and flutterfire (which allows me to use flutter and firebase). With flutterfire I am using [firebase_auth](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth#-readme-tab-). I stopped development for a few weeks and came back to my app not working. I narrowed the issues down to it being my firebase_auth not working. In order to test this, I created a brand new firebase app on Android Studios and tried to connect it to flutterfire. I did all the necessary steps to do this and decided to first test [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore#-installing-tab-) to see if it would work. It did. As soon as I added the line for firebase_auth in my pubspec.yaml file my app would not even build. The errors I get are below. I have tested previous versions of flutter_fire as well.

```
D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file. Try supplying a 
main-dex list.
methods: 65968 > 65536

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/5.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/6.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/7.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/8.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/9.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/303.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/304.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/305.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/306.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/307.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/308.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/309.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/310.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/311.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/312.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/313.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/314.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/315.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/316.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/317.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/318.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/319.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/320.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/321.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/322.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/323.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/324.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/325.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/326.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/327.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/328.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/329.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/330.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/331.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/332.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/333.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/334.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/335.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/336.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/337.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/338.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/339.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/340.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/341.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/342.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/343.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/384.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/390.jar, /Users/nolan/Documents/development/lp_2/lp_2/build/app/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/396.jar
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at 
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Finished with error: Gradle build failed: 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem looks more Android related and not iOS or Flutter.
If your minSdkVersion is set to 21 or higher, all you need to do is set multiDexEnabled to true in your module-level build.gradle file, as shown here:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 21 
    targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
...
}
```

More info: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex especially if minSdkVersion < 21